# RESTHeart Error When Trying To Load CSV Data

Tags: mongodb, csv, restheart

I try to load csv data by using:

```
given().
contentType("text/csv").
body("num,name,val\n1,dror,x\n2,amir,y").
when().
log ().
all ().
post("csv?db=restheart&coll=poi&id=0").
then().log().ifError()
```

I get status 400:

```
"message": "Content-Type request header must be 'text/csv'"
```

although the header seems right:

```
                Content-Type=text/csv; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

full log following:

```
Request path:   http://localhost:8080/csv?db=restheart&coll=poi&id=0
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=text/csv; charset=ISO-8859-1
Cookies:        <none>
Body:
num,name,val
1,dror,x
2,amir,y
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Powered-By: restheart.org
Auth-Token-Location: /tokens/admin
Authentication-Info: nextnonce="moqjKcH05wkNMTU4NTk1NDY2OTEwNe2jU1Xuay1TK5O7rrmyiDA=",qop="auth",rspauth="d31b66e99f7dbb1c339b17741f9380c5",cnonce="f1843d31ec429268",nc=00000001
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location, ETag, X-Powered-By, Auth-Token, Auth-Token-Valid-Until, Auth-Token-Location
Date: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 22:57:49 GMT
Auth-Token: 16p0go30vzwa3ju0h839zn4wfnipcy914g56b5t0xkjh9yotxa
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Auth-Token-Valid-Until: 2020-04-03T23:12:49.109466Z
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 142

{
    "http status code": 400,
    "http status description": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Content-Type request header must be 'text/csv'",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/csv"
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the [code](https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/blob/master/mongodb/src/main/java/org/restheart/mongodb/plugins/services/CsvLoader.java) of the CsvLoader service (that handles the request) and it checks Content-Type to be exactly `text/csv`, so I think the problem is with the additional charset substring `; charset=ISO-8859-1`

Force the Content-Type header to be exactly just `text-cvs`.

I also fixed this bug (see [commit 47fa0821](https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/commit/47fa082139b1e2ba3a1a25b5efbbcfded1c4c7c1)). Fix will be included in upcoming v5.0 release.